# How do I get a multipage site from GitHub Pages' automatic generator?

Tags: github, markdown, documentation-generation, github-pages

I am using the 'Automatic Generator' of GitHub Pages, and I see it only generates a single index.html and other web resources.

How it works if I want to have a multi-page website generated from other markdown files?

Comment: This isn't an answer but you may like [Scriptogr.am](http://scriptogr.am/) for providing this functionality if you have Dropbox. For markdown and Github you really need a static site generator such as [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). The way GitHub Pages is described is a little misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pull the generated page, make any modification and addition you like (including adding new pages and links between the pages), then commit and push.

The generated single page helps you to make you start. You can duplicate its layout to generate other similar-looking pages by hand.

<s>See [Help](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator).</s>

Comment: That's a pity it only 'helps me to start', since after then I need to double work on my project site to keep in sync README.md, the wiki, and the site. It may help at the start, but it may un-help afterward. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you hope it to keep everything in sync for you, and generate content magically?

Comment: If I have many sources of markdown in my project, why not being able to regenerate the site with multiple pages? After I change something on my `master` branch I could just regenerate the gh-pages to have the site updated automatically. That's the beauty of documentation-generation. Isn't it?
And, btw, even for a start, a single page is quite a limitation.

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano if magic is what you want, perhaps what you need is not a static site, but a site that dynamically (via javascript and the GitHub API) pulls the current state of your README and generates HTML content from the README on the fly. Definitely possible, and it removes the burden of doing any syncing work when you update your READMEs

Comment: First you can separate layout from content like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024594/how-do-i-prevent-the-github-pages-automatic-generator-to-remove-everything-bef/14835530#14835530

Then you can generate multiple pages with the script substituting links in them. I did it as a custom script but it's not too difficult to make a generic solution: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/gh-pages/generate

Answer (score 23):

You can get github to generate .html files from .markdown files by ensuring the top of the .markdown starts with the ---- block like this:

```
---
title: This will be used as the title-tag of the page head
---

hello
=====

**You are here!**
```

Found this here:
http://xlson.com/2010/11/09/getting-started-with-github-pages.html

Comment: Also, be sure not to make the same silly mistake as me; ensure you have checked out the branch , whether `master` or `gh-pages`, which your repository is actually serving!

Answer (score 16):

Github will automatically create pages for you, if you include the markdown file.

- index.html - `yourname.github.io/project-name/`
- about.md - `yourname.github.io/project-name/about`
- foo.md - `yourname.github.io/project-name/foo`

Tested this and working.

If you want to get into the really fun stuff - you need to get into Jekyll  http://jekyllrb.com/

Answer (score 4):

Github Pages uses the [Jekyll site generator](http://jekyllrb.com) which suports converting any number of markdown files to HTML for you, and applying the surrounding template via a layout file.  See github's documentation on using Jekyll: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages

The trick is that you have to [download a jekyll template/theme](http://jekyllthemes.org/) and include it in your gh-pages branch on your own (standard jekyll configuration), instead of just allowing Github Pages to auto-generate the one file using its own built-in themes.

Answer (score 3):

- GitHub Pages' automatic generator only generates one page.
- You can **add the new file directly**, github page publishes all data (including data inside the subfolders) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just made [gh-pages-generator](https://github.com/epoberezkin/gh-pages-generator) - the utility to generate site with the navigation from multiple markdown files having links to each other.

Answer (score 0):

"Github pages" hosts web page from index.md / readme.md as main page . However if you have an index.html file then it'll be hosted from html file.However , if you are trying to host a multi page website using "Jekyll themes" then Jekyll theme is not straightaway deployed in subsidiary pages .

Case 1) You are using markdowns to host your pages
index.md -> main page
page1.md -> page 1 of your website
..
so on

To generate a multiple page website using github page just give **relative path to the required page without extension** i.e.
make a button

```
<a href="./page1">Go to next page</a>
```

And by clicking on this button you will be directed to page1 **with jekyll theme deployed**