# How do I prevent the GitHub Pages "Automatic Generator" to remove everything before regenerate the site?

Tags: github, markdown, documentation-generation, github-pages

I created a wonderful GitHub Pages [website for my little project](http://lviggiano.github.com/owner/), and I added some other pages into the `gh-pages` branch.
My problem is that, everytime I regenerate the website from 'Settings=>Automatic Page Generator', everything is cleaned up and I have to restore the files manually.

Is there a way to prevent, or work around this?

It would have been much better if the Automatic Generator was just overwriting his stuff without removing existing files.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Checkout the `gh-pages` branch.
2. mkdir `_layouts`
3. move `index.html` to `_layouts`
4. edit `_layouts/index.html` replace the the inner html of the contents section with `{{content}}`
5. make new file `index.md`
6. Paste markdown content of automatic page generator into `index.md`
7. prepend the following to `index.md`

   ```
   ---
   layout: index
   ---
   ```
8. create `_config.yml`
9. include the following in `_config.yml`:

   ```
   markdown: kramdown
   kramdown:
      auto_ids: true
   ```

   *this step is to match github's markdown syntax*
10. add & commit changes, and then push branch back to github.

Now you can simply edit `index.md` from the [gh-branch in your github source browser](https://github.com/lviggiano/owner/tree/gh-pages) and it will update using [jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages) automatically and not mess with anything in your gh-branch.

You can also make more items editable in the layout using place holder `{{page.varname}}` and then adding `varname:your text` to the header of your `index.md`.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thank you! I had to change `layout:index` to `layout: index` to get this to work however. Otherwise I get a "deep_merge" error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why doesn't Github provide at least a button to do this, in fact? </rant>

Comment: It works but it does not create anchors that page generator creates... Maybe there is some Jekyll setting that would do it?

Comment: Ok, I added Jekyll config to include IDs for # links to work

Comment: Kinda, github is switching to kramdown rendering only in the future, the config should probably switch to generating id's using that rather than redcarpet https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0

Comment: In nowadays, 2016, are there  (more) a simple process?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some tries I found the solution.

I noticed that the only file changed for my site was the index.html, the rest of the generated site was the same. Inside the index.html there was a `<section>content</section>` tag that was containing the html generated from the markdown.

So I created two files `header.inc` and `footer.inc`, that contained the "static" part for the index page. The content part should have been generated from the `README.md` file.

I found that there is an API provided by github to [render a RAW markdown in raw mode](http://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/#render-a-markdown-document-in-raw-mode) to html.
So, last piece of the puzzle was to obtain a permalink for the README.md of my project, with the RAW content; which I happened to find [here](https://raw.github.com/lviggiano/owner/master/README.md).

So I wrote this [simple bash script](https://raw.github.com/lviggiano/owner/gh-pages/bin/autogen) that regenerates the index.html alone, without touching the rest of the site:

```
#!/bin/sh
PG_DIR=$(dirname $0)
RAW_README_URL=https://raw.github.com/lviggiano/owner/master/README.md
GITHUB_API_URL=https://api.github.com/markdown/raw

cat $PG_DIR/header.inc
curl -s $RAW_README_URL | curl -s --data-binary @- -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' $GITHUB_API_URL 
cat $PG_DIR/footer.inc
```

Then I just launch the script as:

```
$ cd myproject
$ git checkout gh-pages
$ git pull origin gh-pages:gh-pages
$ ./bin/autogen > index.html
$ git commit -m "updated index.html from latest README.md" index.html
$ git push origin gh-pages:gh-pages
```

See the implementation details [here](https://github.com/lviggiano/owner/tree/gh-pages/bin).

I tested with the "Leap Day" layout; but I suppose it works also for the others.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible. GitHub wipes the gh-pages repository when you do a "generate". Best you can do is what you are doing now. Another option might be not to use the GitHub page generator to change styles, but to find the source of the styles (they're probably on GitHub somewhere) and manually change them by committing changes (substitute the css files and other minor tweaks)

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#global-configuration) Jekyll to skip certain directories with the `exclude` option.

(Note that Jekyll has a `keep_files` option -- that is for the files in the `destintation` directory.)